# Error during export data from SQL Server to Azure using SQLServerBulkCopy

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I try to export data from SQL Sever to Azure using ODI and custom LKM.
The steps in my LKM look:

[image]

In step "Load data" I use SQLServerBulkCopy but when KM tries execut *bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName(destinationTable);*

It receives the error:

[image]

> ODI-1228: Task SrcSet0 (Loading) fails on the target MICROSOFT_SQL_SERVER connection BJE-Azure-TEST.
>       Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '/'.
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddb_.b(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddb_.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddb9.b(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddb9.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.v(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddq.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.ddj.m(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddel.e(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddel.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.a(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddel.v(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddel.r(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLCommand.execute(SQLCommand.java:163)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLExecutor.execute(SQLExecutor.java:102)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLExecutor.execute(SQLExecutor.java:1)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:50)
>           at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.processTask(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2925)
>           at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.treatTask(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2637)
>           at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessStep.treatAttachedTasks(SnpSessStep.java:577)
>           at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessStep.treatSessStep(SnpSessStep.java:468)
>           at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSession.treatSession(SnpSession.java:2093)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$2.doAction(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:380)
>           at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:216)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.doProcessStartSessTask(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:312)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.access$0(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:304)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$StartSessTask.doExecute(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:874)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:133)
>           at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:84)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Cod in "Load data" step:

```
<%

        import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc;
        import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy;

        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.sql.Statement;

        //String        selectQuery             = "select TOP(10) " +odiRef.getColList("", "[EXPRESSION]", ", ", "", "")+ " from " +odiRef.getSrcTablesList("", "[SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME] AS [POP_TAB_ALIAS]", ", ", ""); //+ " where (1=1) " +odiRef.getJoinList("and ","([EXPRESSION])"," and ","") + odiRef.getFilterList("and ","([EXPRESSION])"," and ","") + odiRef.getGrpBy() + odiRef.getHaving();
        String      selectQuery             = "select TOP(10) R03_DATA.Id, R03_DATA.ItemId, R03_DATA.StepId, R03_DATA.StepName, R03_DATA.ResultState, R03_DATA.ResultString, R03_DATA.ResultDecimal, R03_DATA.LimitLow, R03_DATA.LimitHigh, R03_DATA.ComparisonType, R03_DATA.Unit, R03_DATA.StationNo, R03_DATA.FailGroup, R03_DATA.ResultType, R03_DATA.Report, R03_DATA.Error, R03_DATA.Executiontime from dbo.r03_data AS R03_DATA ";
        String      sourceUrl                   = "***connection to MS SQL***";
        String      destinationUrl      = "***connection to Azure ***";        
        String      destinationTable    = "r03_data";
        //destinationTable  = odiRef.getTable("L", "COLL_NAME", "A");

        ResultSet SourceData;
        ResultSet DestinationData;
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        try {
                out.println("--select query: " +selectQuery);
                Connection sourceConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceUrl); 
                Statement stmt = sourceConnection.createStatement();        
                Connection destinationConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(destinationUrl);
                Statement destStmt = destinationConnection.createStatement();
                SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(destinationConnection);
                SourceData = stmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);

                DestinationData = destStmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);
                bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName(destinationTable);

                out.println("--destination table: " +destinationTable);
                out.println("--select query: " +selectQuery);
        }   catch(SQLException se)
        {
                out.println("--Exception Occured while running Flex SQL. :"+se);
        } 
%>
```

I guess that SQLServerBulkCopy tries to write something out to out.println and after that ODI wants to execute it.

I'm also not sure I do it correctly. Exists another method?